# Correct permissions to write file to disk inside SharePoint's EventReceiver

Tags: c#, sharepoint, copy, filestream, event-receiver

I have been working on a PoC in SharePoint, that on an `EventReceiver` handling items added or updated in Document Libraries, has to copy the file in a temporary folder.

I would want to know, is there a way to know which user will be writing the file in the folder? Because as this might be working on different servers, permissions must be given.

Comment: Please check if edited title matches your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) for all disk operations because incoming user is unlikely to have permissions to write anything to server's file system.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    // open/write/close file here. 
    // Avoid touching SPxxxx objects from outside of this delegate
});
```